# Extracting lines from a text file based on first column to text in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, slice

I'm using Windows 7.0 and have Python 3.4 installed. I'm very new to Python. Here is my list. It is a price file. I have thousands of these, but have been trying to get it to work on just one for now.

I am trying to extract only the lines that begin with hfus,ious, or oaus.

```
caus    123456  99.872300000        2
gous    1234567 99.364200000        2
oaus    891011  97.224300000        2
ious    121314  96.172800000        2
hfus    151617  99081.00            2
hfus    181920  1.000000000         2
```

Here is the desired result.

```
oaus    891011  97.224300000        2
ious    121314  96.172800000        2
hfus    151617  99081.00            2
hfus    181920  1.000000000         2
```

Here is what I wrote so far but it's not working. I also would like if it would loop through each file and overwrite the existing file with the truncated list saving it with it's original name. The file 033117.txt represents a date. Every file is saved as mmddyy.txt. Getting it to work on all files would be ideal, but for now if I can get it to work on even one file that'd be nice.

```
inFile = open("033117.txt")
outFile = open("result.txt", "w")
buffer = []
keepCurrentSet = True
for line in inFile:
    buffer.append(line)
    if line.startswith("hfus"):
        if line.startswith("oaus"):
            if line.startswith("ious"):
        if keepCurrentSet:
            outFile.write("".join(buffer))
        keepCurrentSet = True
        buffer = []
    elif line.startswith(""):
        keepCurrentSet = False
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Comment: in the loop, try `beginning_line = line.split()[0]` and then you can do the check with `if 'oaus' in beginning_line`.... Plus I suggest to open the files using `with`

Comment: `if line.split()[0] in ('hfus', 'ious', 'oaus'): #do stuff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement when you open file objects so you do not need to explicitly close the file, it will be closed automatically for you when the indented block is exited.
Reading and filtering from a file and write the results to another file (not overwriting the same file) could be accomplished by using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and selecting the appropriate lines that gives a more concise way to accomplish the task:

```
with open("033117.txt", 'rt') as inputf, open("result.txt", 'wt') as outputf:    
    lines_to_write = [line for line in inputf if line.split()[0] in ("hfus", "ious", "oaus")]
    outputf.writelines(lines_to_write)
```

---

If you want to overwrite the file instead of opening a new additional file and write to it, do the following:

```
with open('033117.txt', 'r+') as the_file: 
    lines_to_write = [line for line in the_file if line.split()[0] in ("hfus", "ious", "oaus")] 
    the_file.seek(0)  # just to be sure you start from the beginning (but it should without this...)  
    the_file.writelines(lines_to_write)
    the_file.truncate()
```

See [open, modes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for open modes.

Comment: Your first example is working, but the overwrite examles are not.         File "read.py", line 3, in <module>
    begin_line = line.split()[0]
NameError: name 'line' is not defined
PS I:\py>

Comment: Fixed. The list comprehension examples work now. In particular I tested the second snippet to overwrite the file and it gives me the output file you expect. I suggest to use those as they're are concise.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out which snippet you're talking about. I tried them all and am getting different errors. I think I'm not piecing it all together if it's not in one block.

Comment: Hope it's clear now, I removed some stuff. I'm able to run with no problems. The first snippet is for opening a file for reading, selecting appropriate lines and writing to a different output file. The second snippet is if you want to overwrite the same file with the selected lines.

Comment: I always get this error with the second one NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Comment: @JayC I don't get the error you get. Anyway, I  modified again. Now you shouldn't get that error in the second case.

Comment: Your latest change works perfectly thank you. I'll use it to study the technique.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('033117.txt') as inFile, open('result.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in inFile:
        if line.split()[0] in ('hfus', 'ious', 'oaus'):
            outFile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
inFile = open("033117.txt")
outFile = open("result.txt", "w")
for line in inFile.readlines():
    if line.startswith("hfus"):
        outFile.write(line)
    if line.startswith("oaus"):
        outFile.write(line)
    if line.startswith("ious"):
        outFile.write(line)
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Even am new to python so there might be many better solutions but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of data processing I suggest using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("033117.txt", header=None, names=['foo','bar','foobar','barfoo'])
df = df[df.foo.isin(['hfus','oaus'])]
df.to_csv("result.txt")
```

Of course, you want to use more meaningful header values ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `with` statement to open your file instead of `outFile = open()`. This should help create less errors :)

```
with open('033117.txt') as inFile, open('result.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in inFile:
        if line.split()[0] in ('hfus', 'ious', 'oaus'):
            outFile.write(line)
```

Comment: This does work, but my real goal is to overwrite the original file.